# Fetching string values for login from database

Tags: android, sqlite

Am developing an android application which has login activity for three types of users implementing three types of user levels. I have created login activity which fetches user level and password from database using the given login username in order to start a respective activity using intents. Now i get a null pointer exception on the database methods.

the db fetching codes are:

```
        public String fetchPassword(String user_name) {
        Cursor cursor;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME_1, 
                new String[] { COLUMN_USER_LEVEL, COLUMN_USER_NAME }, 
                COLUMN_USER_NAME + "='" + user_name + "'", null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

            String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));

            return result;
    }

    public String fetchUserLevel(String user_name) {
        Cursor cursor;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME_1, 
                new String[] { COLUMN_PASSWORD, COLUMN_USER_NAME }, 
                COLUMN_USER_NAME + "='" + user_name + "'", null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

            String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Pless post your logcat error

Comment: @TeRRo cannot copy the logcat

Comment: @user3780419 In the logcat you  can see an option export log from there you can save the logacat folder here and please indent the logcat before saving

Answer (score -1):

```
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Ths is where you should be getting it

```
        String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
```

If there are no records in the db, there will be a null pointer since the cursor is empty. You need to check whether it is, and then continue.

```
        cursor.isAfterLast();
```

will return true if its empty.

The logcat stack trace would be a good place to start looking.

Comment: `query()` never returns `null`; if nothing is found, the cursor object is empty, i.e., `moveToFirst()` returns `false`.